# Sharepoint WorkFlow update Item error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

We have a workflow that checks two lists. If List B has a matching Value in list A, then the workflow changes a column "code" on list A to match what list B Colum "cc" is. When we run the script we get a error at the update item part. It can see that there is a match between two the list, but when it goes to change the column value it errors and put the workflow in a Suspended state.

I was reading online and it looks like it may be a permission issue, but the person running the workflow has full permission on both list and the whole site. Does the workflow need permission to change the value on another list? Do we need to add that workflow to list A? Right now the workflow is being ran from list B. The error is below,

RequestorId: f8de3c17-6a92-200f-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["118"],"SPRequestGuid":["f8de3c17-6a92-200f-9e78-1c49ccce2e7c"],"request-id":["f8de3c17-6a92-200f-9e78-1c49ccce2e7c"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4711"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Sat, 09 Jun 2018 14:18:11 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"WWW-Authenticate":["NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Edit: this is a 2013 workflow, here is the update item info on the workflow, the first part of the workflow checks to make sure there are matching values between to the two list and only runs the update item if there is a match.

[image]

So i ran the workflow again and and i noticed this error: It said retrying in one minute and give me this.
HTTP Unauthorized to https://websitename:Items(1607) Correlation Id: f8de3c17-6a92-200f-b44b-14d51364427e Instance Id: 1bffdd45-970b-48fd-81a7-50d43fc608d0

So it does look like a authorization  issue, but im not sure why. They have owner rights.

Comment: Can you please provide the code? Is it a 2010 workflow?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by code, it was made in as a 2013 workflow. The line it errors out on is the "update item in list a.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 means that you don't have the authorization on the specified list, try to check if there are correct permissions on the lists.

Comment: yes that was what I was reading, the user has full control and is a owner of the site. Also other errors I have seen showed a unauthorized in the message. This error does not say that so I'm not sure what else it can be. Does the workflow need rights to the list? I was reading online about workflow apps, but not really sure. If the user runs the workflow will it use the users rights?

Comment: Try this : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo